# Should I execute mysql-library-end() after each connection close

Tags: mysql, c

New to C and MySQL.  I have an application that makes many calls to MySQL database. 
 Using ValGrind to find memory leaks in program.  Came across the following link:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-library-end.html

My question is should I be running mysql_library_end() after each connection close.

Or

Is it sufficient to run mysql_library_end() at end of program.  I'm currently running my C application as a linux service so if it crashes it just restarts.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_library_end` means that you absolutely cannot be using the library after that unless you reinitialize. I.e. if by "each connection" you mean that there are simultaneous connections, then you **mustn't** call it after each disconnect.